# ASP.Net GridView and Jquery dataTable with checkbox contol

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview, checkbox, datatables

I am working with asp.net gridview and jquery dataTable. I have implemented jquery dataTable in gridview which is like below:

```
                <asp:GridView ID="gvCustomers" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" class="table table-striped"
                    Width="100%">
                    <Columns>
<%--                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkAll" runat="server"
                                    onclick="checkAll(this);" />
                            </HeaderTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="chk" runat="server"
                                    onclick="Check_Click(this)" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>--%>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="CustomerID" HeaderText="Customer ID" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="ContactName" HeaderText="Name" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Country" HeaderText="Country" />
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
```

My java script is like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('[id*=gvCustomers]').prepend($("<thead></thead>").append($(this).find("tr:first"))).DataTable({
            "responsive": true,
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "aoColumns": [
            null,
            null,
            { "bSortable": false }
            ]
        });
    });
</script>
```

I want to add checkbox in side gridview with a header checkbox for check all functionality. Jquery dataTable is not allowing template column inside grid. I need to retrieve values of the checkbox for delete purpose. I also need a link button to redirect to another page inside the grid.
Any help will be thankfully accepted.

Edited:
I have edited my javascript code like:

```
$(function () {
            $('[id*=gvCustomers]').prepend($("<thead></thead>").append($(this).find("tr:first"))).DataTable({
                columnDefs: [{
                    orderable: false,
                    className: 'select-checkbox',
                    targets: 0,
                    responsive: true,
                    sPaginationType: 'full_numbers'
                }],
                aoColumns: [{ "bSortable": false }, null, null, { "bSortable": false }]
            });
        });
```

Now I am getting following output:

[image]

During loading I am getting a warning like "DataTables warning: Non-table node initialisation (INPUT). For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/2" but searching, sorting, paging is working.
Any idea?

Thanks

Partha

Comment: What do you mean by “datatablr not allowing template column” what is error?  Also remove the commented html from gridview if not needed

Comment: The grid is distorted. The header is coming with every row and search and paging option is not showing. The error is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mData' of undefined
    at HTMLTableCellElement.<anonymous> (jquery.dataTables.min.js:90)
    at Function.each (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:21)
    at init.each (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:21)
    ------"

Comment: Maybe the [checkboxes plugin](https://www.gyrocode.com/projects/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/) from Gyrocode would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your `Gridview` markup is **not wrong**, albeit poorly formatted. I've tested your code locally on my machine and un-commented the `TemplateField` code because the checkbox column is essentially what you're looking for.

The problem lies in your `DataTable` invocation. Instead of what you have, I used the following simple selector `#gvCustomers` and it works without the error you've mentioned. Additionally, it is worth ensuring that your `aoColumns` array length matches the number of columns that you have. Lastly, I do not feel the need to use double quotations when defining the `DataTable` options. We are not dealing with JSON, so it's OK to not have the quotations. Hope this helps.

See below:

```
$('#gvCustomers').DataTable({
            columnDefs: [{
                orderable: false,
                className: 'select-checkbox',
                targets: 0,
                responsive: true,
                sPaginationType: 'full_numbers'
            }],
            aoColumns: [null, null, { bSortable: false }, null],
            select: {
                style: 'os',
                selector: 'td:first-child'
            },
            order: [[1, 'asc']]
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Checkbox is coming but  can not get the paging, sorting and filter option.